# how to calcuate seconds left in the current minute of the time

Tags: javascript

I want to update a clock in the UI when the time changes from `12:01` to `12:02`.

I can do a setInterval every 60 seconds, but the beginning might not be on the first second of a new minute. How can I ensure that it starts at the first second?

I think I need to find out how many seconds are left in the current minute and then do a setTimeout that fires setInterval when the seconds elapse.

```
var secondsLeft = ?; //calculate seconds left in this minute

setTimeout(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        //update clock
    }, 1000 * 60);
}, secondsLeft);
```

If `moment.js` makes it easier, that's fine with me.

Comment: Create a new `Date` object, and look at its seconds.

Comment: You do realize javascript dates and times aren't very accurate, and are based on the settings in the users OS, so it could be totally different from user to user ?

Comment: yeah, this is fine. it doesn't have to be accuracy of an atomic clock. I just don't want the time to change half way through at 30 seconds.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this: `secondsLeft = 60 - new Date().getSeconds()`

Answer (score 0):

I would store old value, use requestAnimationFrame to see if browser is ready to render and at the render check if the minute has changed from previous render.